# Is $f(x) = 0$ everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[−1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Suppose we have 
>   $$
> \int_{−1}^1 \sin^n(x)f(x) dx=0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+.
> $$ Show that $f(x) =0$ on $[-1,1]$.

I tried using $u = \sin(x)$, but it didn't really get me anywhere yet. Please, some insight would be gracious.

Comment: If its true for all n, then in particular its true for even n, which should be easy to prove since $sin^{2n}$ is non-negative (equal to 0 at only one point too, which is important), then since f must be identically 0 for even n, and 0 also works for odd n, then f must be identically 0

Comment: Tip: use [approach0](https://approach0.xyz) to find out if the question has been asked already. In this case it seems a class mate asked the same question 5 hours ago.